# How to apply conditional filling in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My CSV file looks like this

```
DATE_TIME,ID,HOUR,MINUTE,VALUE1,VALUE2,TIME,INSPECTION,seconds
2018-11-01 00:00:00,1,0,0,131.8403388480975,163.40706930229611,00:00:00,1,0
2018-11-01 00:20:00,1,0,20,128.66143180880016,182.4166850946821,00:20:00,1,20
2018-11-01 00:40:00,1,0,40,157.9838672230082,177.12826879097582,00:40:00,1,40
2018-11-01 01:00:00,1,1,0,154.74491894762372,177.02056153432287,01:00:00,1,60
2018-11-01 01:20:00,1,1,20,145.17425322202857,170.28572211898428,01:20:00,1,80
2018-11-01 01:40:00,1,1,40,86.33692934233684,161.306233500133004,01:40:00,1,100
2018-11-01 02:00:00,1,2,0,157.70472270832147,175.57007397898963,02:00:00,1,120
2018-11-01 02:20:00,1,2,20,92.04378773072385,152.758855696098315,02:20:00,1,140
2018-11-01 02:40:00,1,2,40,94.91482763887929,164.34713115356462,02:40:00,1,160
2018-11-01 03:00:00,1,3,0,150.58752716935703,152.573995003487525,03:00:00,1,180
2018-11-01 03:20:00,1,3,20,147.64763286003245,181.7346317353725,03:20:00,1,200
2018-11-01 03:40:00,1,3,40,152.00311766772614,169.43438782829136,03:40:00,1,220
2018-11-01 04:00:00,1,4,0,90.67568616871652,165.94364405219294,04:00:00,1,240
2018-11-01 04:20:00,1,4,20,127.6260776280666,154.41327889693226,04:20:00,1,260
2018-11-01 04:40:00,1,4,40,88.35193693321801,86.7514997924824,04:40:00,1,280
2018-11-01 05:00:00,1,5,0,99.44723697225662,61.81705113015809,05:00:00,1,300
2018-11-01 05:20:00,1,5,20,153.28490595395064,70.71671056760238,05:20:00,1,320
2018-11-01 05:40:00,1,5,40,139.53124376248127,86.96902617467873,05:40:00,1,340
2018-11-01 06:00:00,1,6,0,144.5960580946409,53.46091762212306,06:00:00,1,360
2018-11-01 06:20:00,1,6,20,110.05611978038519,73.32550566412914,06:20:00,1,380
2018-11-01 06:40:00,1,6,40,151.21482961729612,50.858838256056316,06:40:00,1,400
2018-11-01 07:00:00,1,7,0,127.88766918064593,52.45266678876003,07:00:00,1,420
2018-11-01 07:20:00,1,7,20,148.72830141013,60.496196118302194,07:20:00,1,440
2018-11-01 07:40:00,1,7,40,83.62908148257569,86.54612924908034,07:40:00,1,460
2018-11-01 08:00:00,1,8,0,113.49475177931873,59.15439348393694,08:00:00,1,480
2018-11-01 08:20:00,1,8,20,139.37377082538475,86.1347823168292,08:20:00,1,500
2018-11-01 08:40:00,1,8,40,104.5216263376223,86.92624219265554,08:40:00,1,520
2018-11-01 09:00:00,1,9,0,152.55680056900144,60.938994790632144,09:00:00,1,540
2018-11-01 09:20:00,1,9,20,140.38896796205978,56.19504976107255,09:20:00,1,560
2018-11-01 09:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 10:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 11:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 12:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 13:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 14:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 15:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 16:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 17:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 18:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 19:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 20:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 21:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 22:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 23:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 23:59:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
```

I would like to apply conditional filling so that the area where VALUE1 value bigger than VALUE2 is blue, and VALUE2 value bigger than VALUE1 is gray. But, I end up seeing only gray color.

[image]

Here is my complete code:

```js
<!--

This is an HTML document that includes a D3.js script. It starts with the head section where the document's title, character encoding, and D3.js library are included. Then, the document's body starts with a header h1 tag, followed by a script tag where the D3.js code is written.

-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>D3 CSV Example</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>D3 CSV Example</h1>
  <script>

    /* ++++++++++++++++++++++++ These are constant variables that define the dimensions of the visualization. The width and height variables define the overall dimensions of the SVG element that will contain the visualization. The margin variable is used to set a margin between the SVG element and the chart. The innerRadius and outerRadius variables define the radii of the two circles that will be used to represent the data. ++++++++++++++++ */
    const width = 954;
    const height = width;
    const margin = 10;
    const innerRadius = width / 5;
    const outerRadius = width / 2 - margin;
    /* ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  +++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/

    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Step 1) Parsing the CSV file ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    d3.csv("synthetic_data.csv", function(d) {
      // Parse the CSV data and return a JavaScript object
      // with the desired properties
      return {
        DATE_TIME: new Date(d.DATE_TIME),
        VALUE1: +d.VALUE1,
        VALUE2: +d.VALUE2,
        INSPECTION: +d.INSPECTION,
      };
    }).then(function(rawdata) {
      // Convert DATE_TIME column to minute-precise time
      rawdata.forEach(function(d) {
        const hour = d.DATE_TIME.getHours();
        const minute = d.DATE_TIME.getMinutes();
        d.minuteTime = hour * 60 + minute;
      });

      let rawdata2 = rawdata.filter(d => d.INSPECTION == 1);

      const minuteScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 1439]) // 0 to 23:59 (24 hours * 60 minutes without -1 or else change to 1439 //- 1)
        .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

      const minuteTimeValues = rawdata2.map(d => d.minuteTime);

      const x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([0, 1439]) // Set the domain using the extent of the "minuteTime" values
        .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]); // Set the desired range

      console.log(rawdata)

      const minValue1 = d3.min(rawdata, d => d.VALUE1);
      const minValue2 = d3.min(rawdata, d => d.VALUE2);
      const maxValue1 = d3.max(rawdata, d => d.VALUE1);
      const maxValue2 = d3.max(rawdata, d => d.VALUE2);

      const yMin = minValue1 < minValue2 ? minValue1 : minValue2;
      const yMax = maxValue1 > maxValue2 ? maxValue1 : maxValue2;

      const y = d3.scaleLinear()
                  .domain([yMin, yMax])
                  .range([innerRadius, outerRadius]);

// Modify the xAxis generator to display only the hour and add padding

const xAxis = (g) => g
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", 10)
  .call((g) => g.selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.range(0, 24)) // create an array of hour values
    .join("g")
      .each((d, i) => d.id = `hour-${i}`)
      .call((g) => g.append("path")
          .attr("stroke", "#000")
          .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.2)
          .attr("d", (d) => `
            M${d3.pointRadial(x(d * 60), innerRadius)}
            L${d3.pointRadial(x(d * 60), outerRadius)}
          `))
      .call((g) => g.append("path")
          .attr("id", (d) => `hour-${d}`)
          .datum((d) => [d * 60, (d + 1) * 60])
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .attr("d", ([a, b]) => `
            M${d3.pointRadial(x(a), innerRadius-10)}
            A${innerRadius},${innerRadius} 0,0,1 ${d3.pointRadial(x(b), innerRadius)}
          `))
      .call((g) => g.append("text")
        .append("textPath")
          .attr("startOffset", 6)
          .attr("href", (d) => `#hour-${d}`)
          .text((d) => d.toString().padStart(2, "0"))
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
          .attr("transform", (d) => {
            const angle = x(d * 60);
            const radius = innerRadius - 20; // reduce the radius to move the labels closer to the center
                        return `translate(${d3.pointRadial(x(d * 60), radius)})`;
          })
      )
  );



      const yAxis = g => g
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", 10)
        .call(g => g.selectAll("g")
          .data(y.ticks().reverse())
          .join("g")
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .call(g => g.append("circle")
            .attr("stroke", "#000")
            .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.2)
            .attr("r", y))
          .call(g => g.append("text")
            .attr("y", d => -y(d))
            .attr("dy", "0.35em")
            .attr("stroke", "#fff")
            .attr("stroke-width", 5)
            .text((x, i) => `${x.toFixed(0)}${i ? "" : ""}`)
          .clone(true)
            .attr("y", d => y(d))
          .selectAll(function() { return [this, this.previousSibling]; })
          .clone(true)
            .attr("fill", "currentColor")
            .attr("stroke", "none")));

      const line = d3.lineRadial()
                    .curve(d3.curveLinearClosed)
                    .angle(d => x(d.minuteTime));

      const area = d3.areaRadial()
                    .curve(d3.curveLinearClosed)
                    .angle(d => x(d.minuteTime))

      const svg = d3.create("svg")
        .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height])
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round");

svg.append("path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
  .attr("d", line
    .radius(d => y(d.VALUE1))
    (rawdata2));

svg.append("path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "green")
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
  .attr("d", line
    .radius(d => y(d.VALUE2))
    (rawdata2));

svg.append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(_, i) {
    const d = rawdata2[i];
    console.log(d.VALUE1);
    if (d && d.VALUE1 > d.VALUE2) {
      return "blue";
    } else {
      return "gray";
    }
  })
  .attr("stroke", "none")
  .attr("d", area
    .innerRadius(d => y(d.VALUE1))
    .outerRadius(d => y(d.VALUE2))
    (rawdata2));


      svg.append("g")
        .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
        .call(yAxis);

      const container = d3.select("body").append("div");
      container.node().appendChild(svg.node());
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this? **My expectation** is to see blue area color from beginning of label 0 to until middle of label 4 and label 5. How can I achieve this? I want to fill the area in blue where the value of VALUE1 is greater than the value of VALUE2, and in gray where the value of VALUE2 is greater than the value of VALUE1.

**EDIT:** Based on answer of @pernifloss, I changed conditional filling by defininig two areas as following:

```
const positiveData = rawdata2.filter(d => d.VALUE1 > d.VALUE2);
const negativeData = rawdata2.filter(d => d.VALUE2 > d.VALUE1);

svg.selectAll(".positive-area")
  .data([positiveData])
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "positive-area")
  .attr("fill", "blue")
  .attr("stroke", "none")
  .attr("d", area
    .innerRadius(d => y(d.VALUE1))
    .outerRadius(d => y(d.VALUE2))
  );

svg.selectAll(".negative-area")
  .data([negativeData])
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "negative-area")
  .attr("fill", "gray")
  .attr("stroke", "none")
  .attr("d", area
    .innerRadius(d => y(d.VALUE1))
    .outerRadius(d => y(d.VALUE2))
  );
```

However, I ended up with this plot. [image]

How can I make apply conditional filling, while keeping circular shape and circular areas? I do not want to have rectangular like areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really have one path with multiple colors.

The only solution I see is to make multiple areas.

Separate your data in multiple set of contiguous “positive” or “negative” area. Then draw an area for each dataset.

[edit] here is my code so far, the result https://imgur.com/FH6Xim7 ...

```
// separate data in positive and negative value
let separated = rawdata2.reduce((a, b,index) => {
    let sub = b.VALUE1 - b.VALUE2;
    if (sub > 0) {
        return {positive: [...a.positive, {...b,index}], negative: [...a.negative]};
    }
    return {positive: [...a.positive], negative: [...a.negative, {...b,index}]};

}, {positive: [], negative: []})
const positiveSets = [];
let previous = undefined
separated.positive.forEach((e)=>{
    //if not contiguous
    if (!previous || previous.index + 1 !== e.index) {
        // create a new set
        positiveSets.push([e]);
    } else {
        // append value to previous set
        positiveSets[positiveSets.length - 1] = [...positiveSets[positiveSets.length - 1], e]
    }
    previous = e;
})
//same for negatives
const negativeSets = [];
previous = undefined
separated.negative.forEach((e)=>{
    if (!previous || previous.index + 1 !== e.index) {
        negativeSets.push([e]);
    } else {
        negativeSets[negativeSets.length - 1] = [...negativeSets[negativeSets.length - 1], e]
    }
    previous = e;
})
```

My area function:

```
const area = d3.areaRadial()
    .curve(d3.curveLinear)
    .angle(d => x(d.minuteTime))
```

en then append all area to graph :

```
const posG = svg.selectAll('.positive').data(positiveSets)
posG.enter().append('path')
    .attr('class','positive')
    .attr('fill','blue') // "positive" color
    .attr("d", (d)=>area
        .innerRadius(d => y(d.VALUE1))
        .outerRadius(d => y(d.VALUE2))
        (d));

const negG = svg.selectAll('.negative').data(negativeSets)
negG.enter().append('path')
    .attr('class','negative') // "negative" color
    .attr('fill','red')
    .attr("d", (d)=>area
        .innerRadius(d => y(d.VALUE1))
        .outerRadius(d => y(d.VALUE2))
        (d));
```

Comment: Is it possible to define this in a way that it will work for different data? Or will I have to change it according to new data? I would really appreacite if you could provide minimal example

Comment: You can compute those sets pragmatically, so it will work for any given set of data, I'm working on a working example I'll post it as soon as I have something usable

Comment: I have just applied your idea. Please see the EDIT section of my main post

Comment: Nice job, on your area you can change `d3.curveLinearClosed` to `d3.curveLinear`, so your paths are not linked. I ended up with something like this : https://imgur.com/FH6Xim7

Comment: that is weird because after changing to d3.curveLinear, I still end up seeing same linked area path. Could you share me your complete code?

Comment: I think you created only 2 areas, positive and negative.... it's more complicated than that, you have to create one area BY contiguous positive (or negative) value, I updated my answer to include my code, but it's not really readable.

Comment: your approach works ike a char. but, why the area in cros declines are not filled?

Comment: Because the crossing point does not match an entry in your dataset. I think you have to calculate all crossing point to add to area dataset if you want to fill them.